# How to parse HTML data from JSON and render it in UIWebView (using Swift 3.0)

Tags: javascript, html, json, swift, uiwebview

I'd like to use JSON2HTML to parse the HTML data from JSON and render it in an UIWebView (using Swift 3.0). Please let me know how to achieve it. Thanks in advance!

Here's what I've tried:

```
let jsfile1 = try!String(contentsOfFile: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "json2html", ofType: "js")!)

func loadJS()
{
    var getData={}
    var context = JSContext()
    var valSwiftyJson:JSON = [:]
    var test = context?.evaluateScript(jsfile1)

    let testFunction = test?.objectForKeyedSubscript("json2html")

    let urlString = //Have removed the URL string due to restrictions
    Alamofire.request(urlString,encoding:JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON
        { response in
            if let alamoJson = response.result.value
            {
                let swiftyJson = JSON(data:response.data!)
                valSwiftyJson = swiftyJson["FormInfo"]["Form"]
                print(valSwiftyJson)
            }

    }
    let result = testFunction?.call(withArguments: [getData,valSwiftyJson])
    webView.loadHTMLString((result?.toString())!, baseURL: nil)
}
```

Finally, I managed to solve the issue by creating an index.html file (locally stored) and I referred the JSON2HTML library inside it. I then added the JSON(HTML inside) content dynamically to it each time whenever I needed to convert JSON to HTML. At last I load the final index.html in the UIWebView (it worked like charm).

Comment: can you show us your code you have tried so far, better share it on jsfiddle or something

Comment: @user3775217 I've added the coding as you've asked

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about this [library](https://github.com/moappi/json2html) as JSON2HTML ? If so, I don't think there is a library for translating the JSON elements to HTML in Swift.

Do you plan to download the JSON elements from a back-end ? Then, as there is a node.js wrapper to JSON2HTML, I would recommend to do the translating from JSON to HTML on the same server. Thus you would just download the HTML compiled data and rendering it in the `UIWebView` would be as easy as this line of code (in Swift 3) :

```
// html is the HTML data downloaded from your back-end
webView.mainFrame.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL: nil)
```

Comment: I get a JSON file as a server response wherein there will be HTML forms embedded in JSON itself. I got to find a way out to display those forms dynamically (and I'm planning to reuse the existing HTML tags in my Xcode 8 - swift 3 project) using UIWebView. I'd like to refer the JSON2HTML js file using JavaScriptCore or I'd have to find some existing framework for Swift to do this task!

Comment: Yes. The exact JSON2HTML library that you've added link for.